# Limiting the Accelerator movement area in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, accelerometer

```
void Update(){
    float accel = Input.acceleration.x;
    transform.Translate(accel, 0, 0);
}
```

Above is my current code for accelerator control in my game. I want to be able to tilt my phone left and right and the character will move left and right. The code works fine, but the character moves outside the screen. I tried Mathf.Clamp on the accel value and also tried clamping the transform.position but neither work and just seem to change the speed of the accelerometer control.

I need a way to dynamically limit the characters movement within any screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you want to keep an object clamped within the visible area. To achieve this you could use the Viewport.

```
Vector3 pos = this.transform.position;
Vector3 viewportPos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(pos);
if (viewportPos.x < 0f) Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f, pos.y, pos.z));
else if (viewportPos.x > 1f) Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1f, pos.y, pos.z));
```

Comment: I assume you put this script in the update function? Cause I tried that and it didn't work. For reference, I'm making a 3D flight game thing and so there's no natural edges or walls to keep him in. Also yes to your assumption. I want to make sure the character can move left and right with the tilt controls but should be stopped when he goes to far

Comment: Yep, this code goes into an update function. If you're not familiar with viewport space – it's like screen space coordinate but with unit values. So it goes from 0 to 1 on both axes (x and y). This makes it easy to clamp objects within the visible area.

Comment: Another solution could be is adding 2D colliders around the visible area and parenting them to the camera. However this will only work if main object is also using physics.

Comment: Hmm, I tried using the WorldToViewPortPoint idea but the character just went right through them. Completely ignored the clamping. I also tried making some floating colliders around the character that moved with him and setting his accel to 0 as someone else suggested, but that didn't work either. I also tried making it so there was a hard lock bool on the translate when he hit the invisible walls but I'm not sure how you would 'unlock' him once he moves away from the wall.

Comment: [Perhaps some code from a real project will help you](https://bitbucket.org/IggyZuk/smash/src/master/Assets/Scenes/Game/Scripts/Utils/WorldUtils.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could set colliders as triggers alongside the track and set accel variable to 0 if the object is touching the trigger